# Oracle update to split a row into two in safest way with rollback

Tags: sql, string, oracle, split, rollback

I'm working on an existing table that has data similar to:

ID | Name | OldValue | NewValue

these columns have data that is similar to:

14 | name | 'x=>y / zs / z

where the old and new values show a change between values.

What I'd like to do is split these so that this is the result:

15 | name | 'x=>y' | 'x=>s'
16 | name | 'z

I need to safely split this row into two separate rows and then delete the existing data making sure that I'm able to roll back any changes should it hit the fan.

My thoughts are that I should perhaps put all the values into a temporary table where the clauses match what I need.  Then use this table to insert the new rows, after which it should be safe to remove the existing rows and the temporary table.
I'm not sure if this is correct and so I was looking for some advice.

Comment: No need to use a temporary table.  Just do the work in a transaction.  Unless your front end happens to be configured to commit automatically, which is something you should disable on principle, everything you do is part of a transaction.  Your changes won't be visible to others until you `commit` and you can always `rollback` if you're not happy.

Comment: @JustinCave, thanks for taking the time to post.  So, I can just do my insert into where x = y, delete original and then commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the **INSERT** and **DELETE** in **single transaction**. You can always **ROLLBACK** the transaction if you see any issues.

To split the rows have a look at :

- [Split single comma delimited string into rows](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-using-oracle-sql/)
- [Split comma delimited strings in a table](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-using-oracle-sql/)

For example,

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(str VARCHAR2(100));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES ('ID - Name - OldValue - NewValue');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.
```

**Table Data**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

STR
-------------------------------
ID - Name - OldValue - NewValue
```

**INSERT** after [splitting the rows](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-using-oracle-sql/) and **DELETE** the old row

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2  INSERT INTO t
  3  SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL)) str
  4          FROM t
  5          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(str, '-')+1;
  6
  7  DELETE FROM t WHERE instr(str, '-') > 0;
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Check the table data**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

STR
---------------------
ID
Name
OldValue
NewValue
```

Seems good. The rows are now inserted after splitting the delimited string, and then deleted the old row.

**ROLLBACK** and check the table data

```
SQL> ROLLBACK;

Rollback complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

STR
-------------------------------
ID - Name - OldValue - NewValue
```

So, you are back to the same row.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! :)  I don't think I explained the data properly in my question, assuming that ID, Name, OldValue and NewValue are already columns, how could I apply your approach to that?

The string within the value columns is what I'll be using for the where clause.  Thanks!

Comment: @SteveGreen It is not clear how are you splitting the row? Anyway, if you know the rule to split the row, then apply the same logic and do the insert and delete in a single transaction in `BEGIN-END` block as I have shown above.