# Oracle: Inserting a row using values from existing table and new values

Tags: sql, string, oracle, split

I'm having difficulties with splitting a single row into two individual ones.

My test schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE T
    (id int, 
     old varchar2(24), 
     new varchar2(24))
;
```

where old and new are strings that need to be split, an example row:

```
  INTO T (id, old, new)
     VALUES (14, 'L-D / T-E', 'L-E / T-E')
  INTO T (id, old, new)
     VALUES (14, 'L-D / T-E', 'L-D / T-D')
  INTO T (id, old, new)
     VALUES (12, 'L-D / T-E', 'L-E / T-D')
```

In this example 'L' has changed in row 1, 'T' has changed in row 2 and both have changed in row 3

The table is:

```
ID  OLD         NEW
14  L-D / T-E   L-E / T-E
14  L-D / T-E   L-D / T-D
12  L-D / T-E   L-E / T-D
```

I'm trying to split these so that the resulting table will have individual rows for each significant change such that the result will look like:

```
ID  OLD     NEW
1   L-D     L-E  //for existing row 1
2   T-E     T-D  //for existing row 2
//then two rows for existing row 3
3   L-D     L-E 
4   T-E     T-D
```

once these rows have been inserted, i'd then like to delete the existing rows.

I've set up a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0213a/1 - bear in mind I'm updating this as I work so it may look like a train wreck at any given point.

Thanks for any help.

EDITED WITH UPDATE:

I'm trying this but obtaining more data than I require, I think there's an issue with the where clause:

```
drop table t;
CREATE TABLE T
(id int, 
 old varchar2(24), 
 new varchar2(24))
;

INSERT ALL

  INTO T (id, old, new)
     VALUES (12, 'L-D / T-E', 'L-E / T-E')
  INTO T (id, old, new)
     VALUES (13, 'L-D / T-E', 'L-D / T-D')
  INTO T (id, old, new)
     VALUES (14, 'L-D / T-E', 'L-E / T-D')



SELECT * FROM dual
;

SELECT * FROM T;

--insert into t (id, old, new) values (1,'dasdsad', 'asdasd');

BEGIN
INSERT INTO t (id,old, new) 

  WITH DATA AS
      (SELECT id,OLD, new
      FROM t
      WHERE 
      --multiple changes
      --(SUBSTR(OLD,3,1) <> SUBSTR(NEW, 3,1)
      --AND SUBSTR(OLD, 9)    <> SUBSTR(NEW, 9))
      --OR
      (--row 2
      (SUBSTR(OLD,3,1) = SUBSTR(NEW, 3,1)
      AND SUBSTR(OLD, 9)    <> SUBSTR(NEW, 9))
      )
      OR
      (--row 1
      (SUBSTR(OLD,3,1) <> SUBSTR(NEW, 3,1)
      AND SUBSTR(OLD, 9) = SUBSTR(NEW, 9))
      )
      )

    SELECT id, trim(regexp_substr(OLD, '[^/]+', 1, LEVEL)) OLD,  
           trim(regexp_substr(NEW, '[^/]+', 1, LEVEL)) NEW
    FROM DATA
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(old, '/')+1;




END;
 /
```

The output:

```
    12  L-D / T-E   L-E / T-E
13  L-D / T-E   L-D / T-D
14  L-D / T-E   L-E / T-D
12  L-D L-E
12  T-E T-E
13  T-E T-D
13  L-D L-D
12  T-E T-E
13  T-E T-D
```

row 12 is being targeted 3 times when it should just be once.

Comment: There is no problem with the logic to split the string, the only reason you are getting extra rows is the cyclic loop not restricted in the connect by clause. The example I gave is for only 1 row. When you apply it on a table with multiple rows, you need to do the way I have explained here lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-using-oracle-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be simple approach to:

- Identify the row to split using **SUBSTR**
- split the row using **REGEXP_SUBSTR**

To identify the row to split:

```
SUBSTR(OLD,3,1) <> SUBSTR(NEW, 3,1)
   AND 
SUBSTR(OLD, 9)  <> SUBSTR(NEW, 9)
```

To split the rows have a look at :

- [Split single comma delimited string into rows](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-using-oracle-sql/)
- [Split comma delimited strings in a table](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-using-oracle-sql/)

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT OLD
  3    FROM t
  4    WHERE SUBSTR(OLD,3,1) <> SUBSTR(NEW, 3,1)
  5    AND SUBSTR(OLD, 9)    <> SUBSTR(NEW, 9)
  6    )
  7  SELECT trim(regexp_substr(OLD, '[^/]+', 1, LEVEL)) OLD
  8  FROM data
  9    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(OLD, '/')+1;

OLD
------------------------
L-D
T-E

SQL>
```

Now all you need to do is **INSERT** with the above **SELECT** statement and **DELETE** the old row as I demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31759243/3989608).

Comment: Just so I can see whats happening here:  So, we're creating a subset of data using 'with data as' by utilising a substring, this subset is called data? - We're then selecting from that subset where 'LEVEL' is the name of the regex match?  Connect by is a matcher?

I don't fully understand everything that's happening but I have a  much better idea.  
Would you mind having a peek at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0213a/25 please and telling me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: would you mind having a look at the updated post please?

Comment: @SteveGreen, There is no problem with the logic to split the string, the only reason you are getting extra rows is the cyclic loop not restricted in the connect by clause. The example I gave is for only 1 row. When you apply it on a table with multiple rows, you need to do the way I have explained here lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-using-oracle-sql/